# How can I change JavaScript HTTP post request code to C#, using 'no-cors'?

Tags: javascript, c#, http, http-headers, cors

I am trying to do the same thing that is done in the JavaScript code but in C#. The end result would be that I want to automate this task from a C# code where I will create these files manually. This code is being used for the web page in order to achieve its goal:

The First function is placing the file in a buffer a place.

```
        function FileIOU(file: File, backendUrl: string, dispatch: any) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onerror = reject;
                reader.onload = async () => {
                    await fetch(`${ backendUrl}/ www.FileIOU?filename =${file.name}`, {
                        method: 'POST',
                        body: reader.result,
                        mode: 'no-cors',
                    }).then(resolve).catch (err => {
                        console.log('FileIOU', err);
                        dispatch(consoleOutputAction('Failed to send file: ' + file.name, 'error'));
                        reject();
                    });
                };
         reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

The Second function is calling this file to be run on the site.

```
          fetch(`${props.configuration.backendUrl}/www.RunFile?name=${e.currentTarget.id}`);
```

The way how I am mimicking this is by:

```
        public async static Task PostFile(string file)
    {
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[] { };
        File.WriteAllBytes(file, byteArray);
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
        var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(byteArray);
        
        var response = await Client.PostAsync(
        "https://localhost/simulatorweb/www.FileIOU?filename="+$"{fileName}"
        , byteContent);
       
    }
```

and the second part is:

```
    public async static Task RunFile(string fileName)
    {
        var response = await Client.PostAsync(
            $"https://localhost/www.RunFile?name="+$"{fileName}", null);           
    }
```

Once I call this function I get the response `405`, though this possible looks like I need to set the 'no-cors' in C# as per the JavaScript, though I am not sure how to do this. But there could be other issues with this, which I am not seeing.

```
{StatusCode: 405, ReasonPhrase: 'Method Not Allowed', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Date: Fri, 30 Oct 2020 06:15:42 GMT
  Connection: keep-alive
  Vary: Origin
  Accept-Ranges: bytes
  Content-Length: 0
  Allow: GET
  Allow: HEAD
  Allow: OPTIONS
}}
```

Comment: Just a quick heads up: You're currently **writing** `0` bytes into the file (with `File.WriteAllBytes`) because you initialized an empty byte array, and as such you are also posting an array of 0 bytes to your server. What you want is to use `var byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(file)`

Comment: CORS is a browser feature. `HttpClient` doesn't use or obey CORS.

Comment: What is the value of backendUrl in your JavaScript version?

Comment: Why write the file at all?

Comment: @MindSwipe using  `var byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(file);` gives me exactly the same error. I can't use this directly in the `Client.PostAsync`, as it complains about the content format. 
@John Ok thanks, so this is not cors issue as I understand.

Comment: @CaiusJard I need to simulate a drag and drop action, so I need to read the file content in a variable and then call the API. the other command would triggering this file (script in it) to run in DB, I can't run it otherwise.

Comment: My confusion was that if you have the bytes in memory, you're writing the bytes to disk then sending the bytes in memory, or you'd have a file on disk and read them into memory.. all in if you already have the bytes in memory then writing them to disk is a bit pointless

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As John has outlined in the comments, no-cors is not a server side thing that you need to replicate. CORS is a browser feature whereby if JavaScript makes a request to download content from somewhere other than where the JavaScript file itself came from, then the browser (as a courtesy) checks with the destination server "for your url x, what places may a JavaScript have been downloaded from and be permitted to access x?" - this gives the server the opportunity to respond with "only JavaScript from these places a,b,c may request my file x" and the browser then makes a judgement as to whether the JavaScript currently running, may access x

You can turn this off if you can tolerate the restrictions that come with doing so, and that's what no-cors does; it changes the browser behavior

As such, you can hopefully see that no-cors is an instruction to the browser and with your c# you're effectively taking the browser out of the equation so it's unlikely that mimicking it will change the server behavior. It's theoretically possible; your server might be coded to refuse access to a url that it hasn't seen an OPTIONS request for recently(browsers in CORS mode send an options first), but it's actually more likely that the root cause is something simpler like you're Posting to an action that is coded to expect a Get

Comment: Ahh, so the cors would only play role if I would drag and drop the file on the actually server. How can I add extra options for the request though, maybe this is the missing link? So I would need to request a header `Client.DefaultRequestHeaders. = 'dummy';` as this? only with a certain option which I am not aware.

Comment: This answer helped. I could get the results with a PUT request.

Comment: The CORS thing would only be relevant if you were making the request using JavaScript, in a browser. It's sort of a copy protection thing that browsers implement, but as you're looking to not have a browser (you're effectively writing your own browser) the CORS thing doesn't apply. Seems like the ultimate sentence hopefully led to a solution; the server wasn't accepting your POST but you solved it with a PUT; this is consistent with a server that expects a PUT yet receives a POST - the response in such a case ought to be "method not allowed"